Prefect worker using docker infrastructure not working properly after deploy
I'm trying to run a prefect worker on a work pool based on a docker infrastructure. I don't know why, it always gives me problems when the worker submits the flow and the container is run up. Maybe it is something related to the network?
This is the error, from the start of the worker to the failed submission.
Worker 'DockerWorker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287' started!
17:08:25.346 | INFO    | prefect.flow_runs.worker - Worker 'DockerWorker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287' submitting flow run 'b25fc6e1-bb76-43f1-84f2-542fab9c6130'
17:08:25.775 | INFO    | prefect.worker.docker.dockerworker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287 - Creating Docker container 'delicate-goose'...
17:08:26.079 | INFO    | prefect.worker.docker.dockerworker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287 - Docker container 'delicate-goose' has status 'created'
17:08:27.284 | INFO    | prefect.worker.docker.dockerworker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287 - Docker container 'delicate-goose' has status 'running'
17:08:27.346 | INFO    | prefect.flow_runs.worker - Completed submission of flow run 'b25fc6e1-bb76-43f1-84f2-542fab9c6130'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 69, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 373, in handle_async_request
    resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 216, in handle_async_request
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 196, in handle_async_request
    response = await connection.handle_async_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 99, in handle_async_request
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 76, in handle_async_request
    stream = await self._connect(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 122, in _connect
    stream = await self._network_backend.connect_tcp(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/auto.py", line 30, in connect_tcp
    return await self._backend.connect_tcp(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/anyio.py", line 123, in connect_tcp
    stream._raw_socket.setsockopt(*option)  # type: ignore[attr-defined] # pragma: no cover
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/cli/_utilities.py", line 41, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 259, in coroutine_wrapper
    return call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/_internal/concurrency/calls.py", line 432, in __call__
    return self.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/_internal/concurrency/calls.py", line 318, in result
    return self.future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/_internal/concurrency/calls.py", line 179, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/_internal/concurrency/calls.py", line 389, in _run_async
    result = await coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/cli/flow_run.py", line 281, in execute
    await Runner().execute_flow_run(id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/runner/runner.py", line 484, in execute_flow_run
    flow_run = await self._client.read_flow_run(flow_run_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/client/orchestration.py", line 1983, in read_flow_run
    response = await self._client.get(f"/flow_runs/{flow_run_id}")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1801, in get
    return await self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1574, in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/client/base.py", line 325, in send
    response = await self._send_with_retry(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/client/base.py", line 249, in _send_with_retry
    response = await send(request, *send_args, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1661, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1689, in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1726, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1763, in _send_single_request
    response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 373, in handle_async_request
    resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 86, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
An exception occurred.
17:08:37.203 | INFO    | prefect.worker.docker.dockerworker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287 - Docker container 'delicate-goose' has status 'exited'
17:08:37.222 | INFO    | prefect.worker.docker.dockerworker dd84ceb0-ef07-42da-93b7-bd43ed98f287 - Docker container 'delicate-goose' has status 'exited'
17:08:37.379 | INFO    | prefect.flow_runs.worker - Reported flow run 'b25fc6e1-bb76-43f1-84f2-542fab9c6130' as crashed: Flow run infrastructure exited with non-zero status code 1.

This is the .yaml for the deployment, it's contained into /src/
# Welcome to your prefect.yaml file! You can use this file for storing and managing
# configuration for deploying your flows. We recommend committing this file to source
# control along with your flow code.

# Generic metadata about this project
name: src
prefect-version: 2.18.0

# build section allows you to manage and build docker images
build:
- prefect_docker.deployments.steps.build_docker_image:
    requires: prefect-docker>=0.3.1
    id: build-image
    dockerfile: auto
    image_name: darioran/tes1_v1
    tag: test_docker_infra

# push section allows you to manage if and how this project is uploaded to remote locations
push: null

# pull section allows you to provide instructions for cloning this project in remote locations
pull:
- prefect.deployments.steps.set_working_directory:
    directory: /opt/prefect/src

# the deployments section allows you to provide configuration for deploying flows
deployments:
- name: testDeploy
  version: null
  tags: []
  description: null
  entrypoint: main.py:get_repo_info
  parameters: {}
  work_pool:
    name: TestPool
    work_queue_name: null
    job_variables:
      image: '{{ build-image.image }}'
  schedules: []

